# Make every new product be assigned to a category

Tags: zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

In Magento, is there a way to make every new product create automatically assigned to a category?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No  natively, a least no that I know of but it is something very simple to do, if you know the category you could observe the catalog_product_before_save event and add the id(s) of the category(ies) - this should take care of it. You could check if the product has a category already as comparison point in order to decide whether or not to proceed. Magento also has a method to return new products which you could use to assign the categories.